# XML transformation to XML in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I have an xml document that I am trying to transform to different xml document with grouping and counts. I have tried text as I have used it in the past and everything works as expected but I am trying to transform to xml and do not see results as expected.

Error: Namespace prefix 'xd' has not been declared

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xd:StudentData xmlns:xd="urn:com.student.report/student_test">
   <xd:StudentRecord>
      <xd:StudentRequisition xd:Descriptor="1858 Economics"/>
      <xd:StudentStatus xd:Descriptor="Pass"/>
      <xd:StudentApplication xd:Descriptor="1858 Economics"/>
      <xd:StudentID>S-1</xd:StudentID>
      <xd:Gender xd:Descriptor="Male"/>
      <xd:StudentDate>2020-01-01-12:00</xd:StudentDate>
      <xd:Total_Score>75</xd:Total_Score>
      <xd:ProfileStudentTestGroup>
         <xd:StudentTest xd:Descriptor="Student Evaluation"/>
         <xd:StudentTest_Status xd:Descriptor="Pass"/>
         <xd:StudentTest_Date>2020-01-31-12:00</xd:StudentTest_Date>
         <xd:StudentTest_Result_Score>75</xd:StudentTest_Result_Score>
      </xd:ProfileStudentTestGroup>
   </xd:StudentRecord>
   <xd:StudentRecord>
      <xd:StudentRequisition xd:Descriptor="1500 Social Service"/>
      <xd:StudentStatus xd:Descriptor="Fail"/>
      <xd:StudentApplication xd:Descriptor="1500 Social Service"/>
      <xd:StudentID>S-3</xd:StudentID>
      <xd:Gender xd:Descriptor="Female"/>
      <xd:StudentDate>2020-01-01-12:00</xd:StudentDate>
      <xd:Total_Score>65</xd:Total_Score>
      <xd:ProfileStudentTestGroup>
         <xd:StudentTest xd:Descriptor="Student Evaluation"/>
         <xd:StudentTest_Status xd:Descriptor="Pass"/>
         <xd:StudentTest_Date>2020-01-31-12:00</xd:StudentTest_Date>
         <xd:StudentTest_Result_Score>65</xd:StudentTest_Result_Score>
      </xd:ProfileStudentTestGroup>
   </xd:StudentRecord>
   <xd:StudentRecord>
      <xd:StudentRequisition xd:Descriptor="1500 Social Service"/>
      <xd:StudentStatus xd:Descriptor="Fail"/>
      <xd:StudentApplication xd:Descriptor="1500 Social Service"/>
      <xd:StudentID>S-4</xd:StudentID>
      <xd:Gender xd:Descriptor="Female"/>
      <xd:StudentDate>2020-01-01-12:00</xd:StudentDate>
      <xd:Total_Score>67</xd:Total_Score>
      <xd:ProfileStudentTestGroup>
         <xd:StudentTest xd:Descriptor="Student Evaluation"/>
         <xd:StudentTest_Status xd:Descriptor="Pass"/>
         <xd:StudentTest_Date>2020-01-31-12:00</xd:StudentTest_Date>
         <xd:StudentTest_Result_Score>67</xd:StudentTest_Result_Score>
      </xd:ProfileStudentTestGroup>
   </xd:StudentRecord>
   <xd:StudentRecord>
      <xd:StudentRequisition xd:Descriptor="1858 Economics"/>
      <xd:StudentStatus xd:Descriptor="Pass"/>
      <xd:StudentApplication xd:Descriptor="1858 Economics"/>
      <xd:StudentID>S-7</xd:StudentID>
      <xd:Gender xd:Descriptor="Male"/>
      <xd:StudentDate>2020-01-01-12:00</xd:StudentDate>
      <xd:Total_Score>85</xd:Total_Score>
      <xd:ProfileStudentTestGroup>
         <xd:StudentTest xd:Descriptor="Student Evaluation"/>
         <xd:StudentTest_Status xd:Descriptor="Pass"/>
         <xd:StudentTest_Date>2020-01-31-12:00</xd:StudentTest_Date>
         <xd:StudentTest_Result_Score>85</xd:StudentTest_Result_Score>
      </xd:ProfileStudentTestGroup>
   </xd:StudentRecord>
</xd:StudentData>
```

**xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:xd="urn:com.student.report/student_test"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
<root>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="StudentRecord" composite="yes" group-by="StudentRequisition/@xd:Descriptor, ProfileStudentTestGroup/StudentTest/@xd:Descriptor">
  <StudentRequisition>
      <xsl:text>{current-grouping-key()[1]}</xsl:text>
      </StudentRequisition>
  <StudentTest>
      <xsl:text>{current-grouping-key()[2]}</xsl:text>
      </StudentTest>  
  <MPass>
      <xsl:text>{count(current-group()[Gender/@xd:Descriptor = 'Male'][ProfileStudentTestGroup/StudentTest_Status[@xd:Descriptor = 'Pass']])}</xsl:text>
      </MPass>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output:**

```
<root>
<StudentRequisition>1858 Economics</StudentRequisition>
<StudentTest>Student Evaluation</StudentTest>
<MPass>1</MPass>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XSLT you declare the namespace prefix as `wd`, probably a typo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.student.report/student_test"
          ^
```

Comment: Hi @hielsnoppe, Thank you for pointing that out. It was a typo on my part. Fixed the original post.

Comment: You're selecting elements like StudentRecord without any namespace prefix, is that a typo too?